# Optimizing a bitmap character drawing algorithm in C#

Tags: c#, graphics, fonts, bitmap, drawing

Is there any way to optimize this:
A character is stored in a "matrix" of bytes, dimensions 9x16, for the sake of the example, let's call it `character`.
The bytes can be values either `1` or `0` , meaning draw foreground and draw background respectively.
The `X` and `Y` variables are integers, representing X and Y coordinates used for the `SetPixel()` function. `BG` and `FG` represent background and foreground colors respectively, both type of `Color`.

The drawing part of the algorithm itself looks like this:

```
for(int i=0;i<16;i++)
{
    for(int j=0;j<9;j++)
    {
        if(character[i][j] == 1)
        {
            SetPixel(X,Y,BG);
        }
        else
        {
            SetPixel(X,Y,FG);
        }
        X++;
    }
    X=0;
    Y++;
}
```

Later on, X incremented by 9 and Y is set back to 0. 
The problem with this algorithm is , when it's called for drawing a string (many characters sequentially), it's extremely slow.

Comment: Why didn't you ggogle this before asking here? (You are required to do so, i.e. show research effort!) -  Many links would have lead to the reason: Locking a bitmap is a slow process. So you need to lock the bitmap once and do all the work on it in that state. __Using GetPixel and also SetPixel implies that each and every time you lock the bitmap.__ Instead of locking a 100x100 bitmap 20,000 times do it once. So: Look up Lockbits! - OTOH 16x9 is so tiny it won't get slow unless you really draw a big lot of characters..

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I'm not really sure what characters mean, however.

- `GetPixel` internally calls `LockBits` to pin the memory
- Ergo Its best to use `LockBits` once and be done with it
- Always call `UnlockBits`
- Direct pointer access using `unsafe` can give you a small amount of performance as well
- Also (in this case) your `for` loops can be optimized (code wise) to include your other indexes.

**Exmaple**

```
protected unsafe void DoStuff(string path)
{

   ...

   using (var b = new Bitmap(path))
   {
      var r = new Rectangle(Point.Empty, b.Size);
      var data = b.LockBits(r, ImageLockMode.ReadOnly, PixelFormat.Format32bppPArgb); 
      var p = (int*)data.Scan0;

      try
      {
         for (int i = 0; i < 16; i++, Y++)
            for (int j = 0, X = 0; j < 9; j++, X++)
               *(p + X + Y * r.Width) = character[i][j] == 1 ? BG : FG;
      }
      finally
      {
         b.UnlockBits(data);
      }
   }
}
```

---

[`Bitmap.LockBits`](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.drawing.bitmap.lockbits(v=vs.110).aspx)

> Locks a Bitmap into system memory.

[`Bitmap.UnlockBits`](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.drawing.bitmap.unlockbits(v=vs.110).aspx)

> Unlocks this Bitmap from system memory.

[`unsafe`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/csharp/language-reference/keywords/unsafe)

> The unsafe keyword denotes an unsafe context, which is required for
>   any operation involving pointers.

---

**Further reading**

[Unsafe Code and Pointers](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/csharp/programming-guide/unsafe-code-pointers/index)

[Bitmap.GetPixel](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.drawing.bitmap.getpixel(v=vs.110).aspx)

[LockBits vs Get Pixel Set Pixel - Performance](https://mfranc.com/programming/operacje-na-bitmapkach-net-1/)

Comment: if you use `Marshal.Copy` to copy the byte array in and out, the code doesn't even need to be unsafe.

Comment: @Nyerguds yeah this is correct and good point, but lockbits is already pinned, using unsafe just saves moving and pinning the array again for pointer access i.e there is no additional overhead

Comment: Well, I have built up quite a suite for editing indexed images, and they all just work with byte arrays. Easy for manipulation.